# Capitalize first letter of TextView in an Android layout xml file

Tags: android, textview, capitalize

I have a TextView in a layout xml file like this:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/viewId"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/string_id" />
```

My string is specified like this:

```
<string name="string_id">text</string>
```

Is it possible to make it display "Text" instead of "text" **without java code**?
(and without changing the string itself either)

Comment: No, it's not possible. You could create a custom TextView though, which capitalizes the text.

Comment: Can you please check my answer as correct if it answered your question?

Answer (score 6):

No. But you can create a simple CustomView extending TextView that overrides setText and capitalizes the first letter as Ahmad said like this and use it in your XML layouts.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CapitalizedTextView extends TextView {

    public CapitalizedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            text = String.valueOf(text.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + text.subSequence(1, text.length());
        }
        super.setText(text, type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, it's the solution I was already using. I was wondering if anyone had a tricky hack to do it directly in the xml :) But I guess it really isn't possible :(

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda frustrating the extents you have to go to for simple modifications but you can't expect them to be able to make everything easy :P Though it would be cool to be able to use Java functions in you xml so you can say something like capitalize('text') and define capitalize as a function in your java code.

Answer (score 3):

I used [Hyrum Hammon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624876/3064486)'s answer to manage to get all words capitalized.

```
public class CapitalizedTextView extends TextView {

    public CapitalizedTextView( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    @Override
    public void setText( CharSequence c, BufferType type ) {

        /* Capitalize All Words */
        try {
            c = String.valueOf( c.charAt( 0 ) ).toUpperCase() + c.subSequence( 1, c.length() ).toString().toLowerCase();
            for ( int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++ ) {
                if ( String.valueOf( c.charAt( i ) ).contains( " " ) ) {
                    c = c.subSequence( 0, i + 1 ) + String.valueOf( c.charAt( i + 1 ) ).toUpperCase() + c.subSequence( i + 2, c.length() ).toString().toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            // String did not have more than + 2 characters after space.
        }
        super.setText( c, type );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Kotlin extension function

```
 fun String.capitalizeFirstCharacter(): String {
        return substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + substring(1)
    }

textview.text = title.capitalizeFirstCharacter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the activity:

```
String userName = "name";
String cap = userName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + userName.substring(1);
```

Hope this helps you.