# android TextView equivalent for textCapSentences

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

```
 android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

is for `EditText`. Does `TextView` have an equivalent function?

Answer (score 0):

Depend on [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType), you can do that, but i have tried and it not work, so i keep searching and the best way is we must custom the `TextView` class: let try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624876/2810231)

Edit: or you can use an `EditText` which can't `editable` :)
Gluck!

Answer (score -1):

```
// try this
<EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@android:style/Widget.TextView"
  android:text="hi how are you"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>
```

Comment: The author asks solution for 『TextView』.